# Window width hard limit in Opera and Firefox?

Tags: firefox, width, opera

Okay... hey guys,
I hope you can help me solve this one, or maybe someone will be able to provide a comprehensible reasoning for the following.

The newer versions of the Opera and Firefox browser are forcing a reduced available width onto websites. I assume that's in order to fit their content better (with less unused space).

However, if a website's content exceeds the width of 1536 px (and your screen resolution is 1920 px in width), the available width is still capped at 1536 (a horizontal scrollbar appears).

I've prepared a demo as well:
http://r00t.li/test/opera_fittowidth_fckup.html

So I think it's a nice feature of those browsers to fit website content to the available width as it often improves the readability, but what on earth can I do if I want/need to utilize the full screen width?

I've toyed around with different meta tag viewport settings, but it hadn't have any effect. I guess that's for mobile devices only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so after some more searching I found the culprit: the DPI setting of windows affects how these browsers display websites. For instance with a DPI of 125%, the Opera and Firefox browser try to apply this not just to their UI, but also to websites by rendering the content bigger (even though the website zoom in the browser is set to 100%), effectively decreasing the available pixel width.

As a web designer, one has apparently absolutely no control over this. And even if a user takes the time to change the windows DPI to 100%, it's not an acceptable solution. Granted, the websites look normal again, but the font-size of the windows UI is tiny - very hard to read.

But I don't want this to become a rant, so again; the solution is to change your windows DPI setting to 100%. This can be done like this:

1. Right click on the desktop and select Screen Resolution
2. Click on "Make text and other items larger and smaller"
3. Choose 100% and save your settings

Very sad that those browser developers made that decision... as if the 100 milliseconds it takes the user to hold Ctrl and tick the mouse wheel one or two times were too much.